# How to calculate / describe relative position (rubix cube)

Tags: algorithm, 3d, pseudocode

This is an algorithmic problem. I can't seem to find a way to compare relative positions of 2 cubes in a rubix cube.

I've numbered all the 20 cubes in my program. and I'm using their this coordinate system, but now that I wanted to model two cubes in relative position I'm having trouble.

[image]

For example, say I saw the two cubes I'm watching in position 8 and 10, then later I saw them in position 12 and 13, well in both situations they're both on the same face of the cube, and they're both across from each other, not adjacent. Relatively speaking, that's the same representation of their location.

(By the way I'm only concerned with the "edge cubes" at this point, that's not the corners, so: 8 10 9 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 positions).

So anyway I thought if I listed every position in relation to each staring point, using the same algorithm to list each one, then I could compare the indexes and if they were the same, the relative position would be the same (but I was wrong, I might be on the right track, but it doesn't always work):

```
08 10 18 16   12  13  14  15    09  11  19  17
09 11 19 17   13  14  15  12    10  08  16  18
10 18 16 08   14  15  12  13    11  09  17  19
11 19 17 09   15  12  13  14    08  10  18  16

12 13 14 15   11  19  17  09    16  08  10  18
13 14 15 12   08  16  18  10    17  09  11  19
14 15 12 13   09  17  19  11    18  10  08  16
15 12 13 14   10  18  16  08    19  11  09  17

16 08 10 18   19  17  09  11    13  12  15  14
17 09 11 19   16  18  10  08    14  13  12  15
18 16 08 10   17  19  11  09    15  14  13  12
19 17 09 11   18  16  08  10    12  15  14  13
```

Consider the following two positions: cube A is at potion 19 and cube b is at 16. they're adjacent on the bottom level. Here's "19" row and it's indices to 16:

```
0  1  2  3    4   5   
19 17 09 11   18  16  08  10    12  15  14  13
```

Now compare that to the relative position of the cube c and d at 13 and 9. C and D are adjacent on the right side, so they should have the same relative position. But my method doesn't determine that.

```
0  1  2  3    4   5   6   7     8   9
13 14 15 12   08  16  18  10    17  09  11  19
```

index 6 is not equal to index 9. Anyway that was my best approach and it took all day to come up with.

Does anyone have any other strategies that come to mind for calculating / expressing relative position between two locations on a cube?

Thanks very much for your help, and consideration on this topic!

Comment: Many things aren't clear I'm afraid.  "So anyway I thought if I listed every position in relation to each star[t]ing point, using the same algorithm to list each one, then I could compare the indexes and if they were the same, the relative position would be the same" -- ???  I have no idea how to interpret the table that follows.  What is a "relative position"?

Comment: Is it correct that you are only interested in the positions and not in the orientation? Each edge cube can have two orientations in the same position.

Comment: @j_random_hacker: He has a certain pattern to traverse the edge cubes from some starting point. When starting from cube 8, he goes accross the top face to cube 10, then accross  the next face to 18, and so on. Starting from cube 9 (just mentally rotate the cube so 9 is where 8 was before) you go accross the top face to 11, then down to 19... See my answer for why this doesn't work to solve the problem in question.

Comment: @Legit I think you made a mistake in the question. You numbered the relative positions with respect to cube 19 from 0 to 6 (in the second listing). However, the cube 16 that you are interested in is at position 5. You also later refer to position 6 where I think it should be 5.

Comment: @lex82 yes it is correct I'm only interested in the positions at this point. (I'm just trying to figure out one thing at a time).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems here:

- I think you made a mistake when you calculated the relative positions from cube 13. I get:

  ```
  0  1  2  3     4  5  6  7     8  9  10 11 
  13 14 15 12    17 09 11 19    08 16 18 10
  ```

  This lines up with the other one, so cube 9 occurs at position 5. Compare this with the first row:

  ```
  0  1  2  3     4   5   6
  19 17 09 11    18 16 08 10    12 15 14 13
  ```

  As required, cube 16 also occurs at position 5 (I think you mixed something up in your question. You mention index 6 when you mean 5. You number the indexes up to 6, but at position 6 there is cube 8, not cube 16. Please check that again).
- The second problem is that given only a cube position without a reference cube for the orientation, there are two ways to number the cubes. Since your cube is not colored, you can rotate the cube by 180 degrees and come to another numbering for the reference cubes. Given that the relative positions for cube 19 are correct, I can also number the relative positions for cube 13 like this:

  ```
  0  1  2  3     4  5  6  7     8  9  10 11 
  13 12 15 14    08 16 18 10    17 09 11 19
  ```

  Note that this is close to your version but indexes 1 to 3 are in a different order. I think you were not consistent in the way you looked at the cube.

The main problem already becomes apparent in this paragraph:

> For example, say I saw the two cubes I'm watching in position 8 and
>   10, then later I saw them in position 12 and 13, well in both
>   situations they're both on the same face of the cube, and they're both
>   across from each other, not adjacent. Relatively speaking, that's the
>   same representation of their location.

For every cube, there are two other cubes being on the same face and across from each other. To eliminate this ambiguity, you have to take orientations into account or reduce the number of relative positions (e.g. index 1 and 3 in your current scheme would denote the same relative position).

Comment: you're right I did count to 6 when I should have counted to 5. I've now fixed that in the question, thanks.

You're right I didn't take orientation of the cube into account. ok, let me work on this and get back to you, thanks!

Comment: ok, so the solution I landed on was making another list, as big as the first, with the opposite orientation for each cube 8-19. so now there's 8.1 and 8.2. If a series of cubes matches the orientation of either .1 or .2 we combine both lists in [concat .1 .2] order which gives us a relative location. Example 5 cubes (x, a, b, c, d, e) in locations (09 14 16 12 10) First list of every edge cube in relation to 09: 09 11 19 17 13 14 15 12 10 08 16 18 indexes: 06 08 09 11 of orientation 9.1. Their signature would be: 06 11 08 09 plus orientation 9.2 which is: 10 07 12 05. thus: 0611080910071205

Comment: Making another list for the other orientation sounds reasonable. However, from there I cannot follow you anymore. However, I'm glad I could help and you make progress.